# Find combinations of values in arrays where each value is larger than the other

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I received a question in a code interview that I unfortunately was not able to solve in an efficiant manner. I solved it as O(n^2) and I believe it can be solved in O(n log n).

Here's my attempt to it, is it the right way to solve it or can it be improved?

## Question

You have arrays `A`, `B` and `C` that all contains `n` integer values. How many combination of values can we find between A, B and C if the value in B have to be higher than A, and C have to be higher than B.

E.g.

```
A = [29, 49, 65]
B = [31, 55, 78]
C = [45, 98, 100]

# Combinations
29, 31, 45
29, 31, 98
29, 31, 100
29, 55, 98
29, 55, 100
49, 55, 98
49, 55, 100
65, 78, 98
65, 78, 100
```

## Solution

I solved it by sorting the lists and then doing a Binary Search for the index closest, and higher than the previous value.

```py
def getClosest(arr, left, right, val, closest=None):
  mid = right-int(abs(left-right)/2)
  if left >= right:
    if arr[mid] == val:
      return val
    return closest

  if arr[mid] == val:
    return mid
  elif val > arr[mid]:
    return getClosest(arr, mid+1, right, val, closest)
  elif val < arr[mid]:
    if closest is None or mid < closest:
      closest = mid
    return getClosest(arr, left, mid-1, val, closest)

  return closest

def getLocationGTE(arr, limit):
  index = getClosest(arr, 0, len(arr)-1, limit)
  if index is None:
    return []
  else:
    return arr[index:]

def countStops(A, B, C):
  A.sort()
  B.sort()
  C.sort()
  total = 0
  for i in range(len(A)):
    a = A[i]
    b_locations = getLocationGTE(B, a+1)
    for b in b_locations:
      c_locations = getLocationGTE(C, b+1)
      total += len(c_locations)

  return total
```

Comment: If you did not forget to add further contstraints, then I doubt that even O(n²) is possible. Consider the arrays `A=[1, 2, ..., n]; B=[n+1, n+2, ..., n+n]; C=[2n+1, 2n+2, ..., 2n+n]`. There are exactly n³ combinations *(a,b,c)* for which *a<b<c*. Just to enumerate these combinations you would need time O(n³).

Comment: @Socowi it is possible because you don't have to list them, only count them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers given so far look a bit complicated to me, so let me add another approach.

The main idea is to calculate the number of combinations using a given B element. It's the number of smaller A elements multiplied by the number of larger C elements.

Let's assume all three arrays are sorted in ascending order. Your example arrays are already sorted, but the fact isn't mentioned explicitly in the text, so maybe we need an initial sort, accounting for O(nlogn).

We need a loop over all B elements, and inside the loop we need to maintain two indexes into the A and C array, the A index `ia` identifying the last A element lower than the B element, and the C index `ic` identifying the first C element larger than the B element. This loop is O(n), as the A and C indexes can't be incremented more than n times.

A Java class implementing the algorithm:

```
public class Combinations {

    // array access guarded against index-out-of-range.
    private static int arrayAccess(int[] array, int index) {
        if (index < 0)                  return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        else if (index >= array.length) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        else                            return array[index];
    }

    public static int combinations(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c) {
        int ia = -1;
        int ic = 0;
        int nCombinations = 0;
        for (int ib=0; ib<b.length; ib++) {
            int bElement = b[ib];
            while (arrayAccess(a, ia+1) < bElement) {
                ia++;
            }
            while (arrayAccess(c, ic) <= bElement) {
                ic++;
            }
            nCombinations += (ia+1) * (c.length-ic);
        }
        return nCombinations;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {29, 49, 65};
        int[] b = {31, 55, 78};
        int[] c = {45, 98, 100};
        int result = combinations(a, b, c);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well nice that you add another answer, but I don't see how my approach is complicated, it's pretty straight forward. It is even easily adopted to work with 4 or more arrays with the same condition, just add more cumulative sum steps, while your approach isn't easily adopted to work with more than 3 arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, it can be solved in O(nlogn).

1. sort all the arrays
2. for each index b in B, count how many elements in C are greater than B[b]

```java
    int[] count = new int[n];
    int c = 0;
    for (int b = 0; b < n; b++) {
        while (c < n && C[c] <= B[b])
            c++;
        count[b] = n - c;
    }
```

3. build the cumulative sum of the counts in reverse

```java
    int[] cumSum = new int[n];
    cumSum[n - 1] = count[n - 1];
    for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        cumSum[i] = cumSum[i + 1] + count[i];
```

4. for each element in A find the first index in B and add the corresponding cumulative sum to the total count

```java
    int total = 0, b = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < n; a++) {
        while (b < n && B[b] <= A[a])
            b++;
        if (b == n)
            break;
        total += cumSum[b];
    }
```

Step 1. takes O(nlogn) and step 2. to 4. are O(n), which gives O(nlogn) overall.

Here is the complete implementation in javascript:

```js
function countCombos(A, B, C) {
  A.sort(function (a, b) {return a - b})
  B.sort(function (a, b) {return a - b})
  C.sort(function (a, b) {return a - b})
  let count = [], c = 0, n = A.length
  for (let b = 0; b < n; b++) {
    while (c < n && C[c] <= B[b])
      c++
    count[b] = n - c
  }
  for (let i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) // building cumSum directly in count
    count[i] = count[i] + count[i + 1]
  let total = 0, b = 0
  for (let a = 0; a < n; a++) {
    while (b < n && B[b] <= A[a])
      b++
    if (b == n)
      break
    total += count[b]
  }
  return total
}

console.log(countCombos([29, 49, 65], [31, 55, 78], [45, 98, 100]))
```

Btw. you are missing 4 combos in your list: [29, 78, 98], [29, 78, 100], [49, 78, 98] and [49, 78, 100], therefore 13 is the correct answer.

Comment: Whats the Big O of my solution? The binary search is O(Log N) but I have nested loops. Is it O(N (Log N)^2) ?

Comment: @MarcusLind Even though you do a binary search, you return all numbers that are greater than the input, which can be an array of size n each time, so the time complexity is O(n^3). It would be O(n^2*logn) if you would only return the number of elements and not the elements themselves on the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is right, we can beat `O(n^2)`, because the sorting and binary search solution generates extra work (elements of arrays `B` and `C` are read multiple times) which we would like to avoid.

#### Solution A - `O(n.log2(n))`

An `O(nlogn)` solution can be constructed using a binary search tree as an auxiliary data structure. We would need to decorate each node with a color, identifying the array from which the node's value was extracted.

Let's use for instance the following color conventions:

- `Amber` for array `A`
- `Blue` for array `B`
- `Cyan` for array `C`

Then, we perform with an in-order depth-first search of the tree, counting the number of `Cyan` nodes, `Cyan -> ... -> Blue` and `Cyan -> ... -> Blue -> ... -> Amber` transitions.

```
BST tree = new BST(AscendingOrder);

for (a: A) { tree.add(new Node(Amber, a)); }
for (b: B) { tree.add(new Node(Blue, b));  }
for (c: C) { tree.add(new Node(Cyan, c));  }

int cyans, cyanThenBlues, solutions = 0;
DFS(tree.root(), cyans, cyanThenBlues, solutions)
```

with

```
DFS(Node node, int& cyans, int& cyanThenBlues, int& solutions) {
   if (node == null) { return; }

   DFS(node.left(), cyans, cyanThenBlues, solutions);            

   cyans += node.color() == Cyan ? 1 : 0;
   cyanThenBlues += node.color() == Blue ? cyans : 0;
   solutions += node.color() == Amber ? cyanThenBlues : 0;

   DFS(node.right(), cyans, cyanThenBlues, solutions);
}
```

If the values of `A`, `B` and `C` are arbitrarily ordered, the construction of the BST costs `O(n.log2(n))`, and the DFS `O(n)`.

However, depending on how close to be sorted the input arrays `A`, `B` and `C` are, the tree may become unbalanced enough for the `O(n.log2(n))` to become too optimistic.

- Average time complexity: `O(n.log2(n))`
- Worst case complexity: `O(n^2)`
- Space complexity: `O(n)`

#### Solution B - `O(n.log2(n))`

It is essentially the same approach as before, the difference is that we first sort the arrays `A`, `B` and `C`, create an auxiliary array of length `3.n` which elements are decorated with colors similarly to the previous solution, populating this arrays with the values of `A`, `B` and `C`, then traverse the array and transitively count the number of transitions of colors we are interested in.

```
sort(A);
sort(B);
sort(C);

// Constructing guards, loose syntax
int[] A' = A + { Integer.MIN_VALUE };
int[] B' = B + { Integer.MIN_VALUE };
int[] C' = C + { Integer.MIN_VALUE };

int[] D = new int[3 * n];
int i, j, k = 0;

for (int t = 0; t < 3 * n; ++t) {
   if (A'[i] >= B'[j] && A'[i] >= C'[k]) {
      D[t] = new Node(A'[i++], Amber);
   }
   else if (B'[j] >= A'[i] && B'[j] >= C'[k]) {
      D[t] = new Node(B'[j++], Blue);
   }
   else if (C'[k] >= A'[i] && C'[k] >= B'[j]) {
      D[t] = new Node(C'[k++], Cyan);
   }
}

int cyans, cyanThenBlues, solutions = 0;
for (int t = 0; t < 3 * n; ++t) {
   cyans += D[t].color() == Cyan ? 1 : 0;
   blues += D[t].color() == cyanThenBlues ? cyans : 0;
   solutions += D[t].color() == Amber ? cyanThenBlues : 0;
}
```

Assuming we are using a quick sort:

- Average time complexity: `O(n.log2(n))`
- Worst case complexity: `O(n^2)`
- Space complexity: `O(n)`

Note that the memory footprint of the second solution will be smaller than the first one (cost of the BST).

**Follow-up comments**

- Assuming the arrays are sorted, `Theta(n)` is the best possible time complexity achievable (because each element needs to be read at least once). The overall time complexity in these solutions is dominated by the sort or the construction of the BST.
- In both cases, the key was to exhibit an ordering relationship spanning all three arrays.
- Could we think of another [sorting algorithm](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) for the array of integers?